# R7RS-small: equivalence of quasiquoted expressions

Tags: scheme, quasiquotes, r7rs

The [R7RS-small standard](https://small.r7rs.org/attachment/r7rs.pdf), section 4.2.8 Quasiquotation on page 20-21 says that

```lisp
(let ((a 3)) `((1 2) ,a ,4 ,'five 6))
```

is equivalent to

- ```lisp
  `((1 2) 3 4 five 6)
  ```

and

- ```lisp
  (let ((a 3))
    (cons '(1 2)
      (cons a (cons 4 (cons 'five '(6))))))
  ```

But not equivalent to:

```lisp
(let ((a 3)) (list (list 1 2) a 4 'five 6))
```

How can the expression above be any different from the first three? All four expressions above evaluate to the same thing: `'((1 2) 3 4 five 6)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is given a few lines before the example (emphasis is mine):

> A quasiquote expression may return either newly allocated, mutable objects or literal structure for any structure that is constructed at run time during the evaluation of the expression. **Portions that do not need to be rebuilt are always literal.**

This means that in:

```
(let ((a 3)) `((1 2) ,a ,4 ,'five 6))
```

the part `(1 2)` inside the quasiquote **must** be treated as a literal, as in `...'(1 2)...` and not as a structure built from its components, like in: `...(list 1 2)...`.

This seems to be an overspecification, since `'(1 2)` prints exactly like `(list 1 2)`, but the first list **cannot** be mutated (or, better, there is an undefined behaviour if mutated), while the second one can be legally mutated.